# Fail Booting on Windows 7 Professional/Ubuntu Dual-Boot

Tags: windows-7, ubuntu, multi-boot, toshiba-laptop

I have the Toshiba NB255 that is dual-booted with Windows 7 Professional and Ubuntu (Linux). I've not been able to access my device lately because of these problems, so I'm going to go through bit by bit of what my issues are in this post.

First, My Device Starts With `Windows Boot Manager` and it says `Choose an operating system to start, or press TAB to select a tool`. So I have Windows 7 and Ubuntu as options.

When I choose Windows 7 it comes up with `Windows Error Recovery`, because it failed to start. Launch Startup Repair takes FOREVER to load, nothing works on it. It all fails. When I select `Start Windows Normally`, the Windows loading screen shows for a very long time and flashes this blue screen, but I can't see what it says as it goes by too fast. I did some messing around and found A way to prevent restarting upon system failure. This is what the blue screen came back with:

```
A problem has been detected and Windows has been shutdown to prevent damage to your computer.
UNMOUNTABLE_BOOT_VOLUME
If this is the first time you've seen this Stop error screen, restart your computer.
If this screen appears again, follow these steps:

Check to make sure any new hardware or software is properly installed.
If this is a new installation, ask your hardware or software manufacturer for any
Windows updates you might need.

If problems continue, disable or remove any newly installed hardware
or software. Disable BIOS memory options such as caching or shadowing.
If you need to use Safe Mode to remove or disable components, restart
your computer, press F8 to select Advanced Startup Options,  and then
select Safe Mode

Techincal Information:

*** STOP: 0x000000ED (0x84A569D0, 0xC0000185, 0x00000000, 0x00000000)
```

I've exhausted all my options including Safe Mode. Again, my model is the Toshiba NB255.

My next problem is Ubuntu, which won't boot either.

I click the Ubuntu Option on the OS selection screen. It then it just stays on a purple screen and does nothing else. I've tried leaving it on all day/night. It does nothing else. I don't know what else to do.

Comment: 1) Can you access the volumes if you boot from a pen drive or a CD/DVD?  2) Can you run checkdisk on the windows volume. That is relative easy to do if you can either boot from a liveCD or if you put the laptops disk in an external HDD to eSATA/Firewire/USB enclosure.

Comment: Alright, I have no CD/DVD Drive, it is a notebook, sadly D:. I just have found a solution, hopefully it works, I've been researching it as well, so I will report back if I have a solution.

Comment: @Hennes Thanks for the concern though. Not a lot of people are looking into this post. :D

Comment: Can't respond to my question myself so here http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/2605/fixing_the_dreaded_unmountable_boot_volume_error/